# how to crop the binary image from the point of the centroid of an image to some extent

Tags: matlab, centroid

After finding out the centroid of the image , i want to crop some object in an image from the centroid point to some extent. I can use regionprops function to identify the centroid.. the thing is how to crop the image based on the centroid point to some region and how to make my object position in an image  to fix at the centre of the whole image.